# mlloaddatabases backup-enabled always true

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

Running "gradle mlLoadDatabases" where my database config file contains:

```
  "database-backup": [
    {
        "backup-id": 1001,
        "backup-enabled": false,
        "backup-directory": ...
```

The scheduled backup that gets created always has **backup enabled** = **true**.
Is there a way to have this created in a disabled state for dev purposes so that the developer can enable it when needed?

TIA

Comment: That looks like the correct format, according to the Manage REST api documentation: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]/properties. Sounds like a good candidate for a bug report, either via support, or perhaps via ml-gradle..

Comment: You can run "gradle --debug mlDeployDatabases" to see the payload being sent. If the payload is correct, then it's a bug with the Manage API.